# Aura Remote Action JSON parse error

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, json, aura, remote-action

An internal server error when trying to pass custom class via SFDC server action

```
public class Estimation {

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal tic {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal go {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal get {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public Decimal probability {get; set;}
}
```

Callout to srever

```
saveEstimation: function (cmp, recordId, estimation, callback) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.saveEstimations");
    action.setParams(
        {
            recordId : recordId,
            est      : estimation
        }
    );
```

And on server side:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Estimation saveEstimations(Id recordId, Estimation est)
```

This is what i get

> (3442602)|FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error

As a workaroud I can serialize object to JSON on js side and deserialize it on server side. I have to do it at this moment but I think it's a bug.

Othe possible option is to retrieve Map as parameter which is also no pretty solution.

Does anybody have any idea what to do with it?

Comment: so **est** or **Estimation**? As far as I know SF does not really like if method/variable names duplicate each other in lighting and apex,

Comment: Variable name is different than class name. Sorry for that. Just updated question.

Comment: Can you also put definition of Estimation in apex and estimation in JS?

Comment: Regarding definintion on JS/Component side is stored in aura:atrribute.
So:
1. Retreive data from server and put it into attribute
2. Update some field
3. Save it to server

Comment: Can you post the exact code of the aura attribute?

Comment: <aura:attribute name="estimation"         type="OpportunityEstimations_C.Estimation" access="private"/>

But issue imo is not related to front-end side. Rather there is some issue with JSON parse on server side.